# Custom admin theme showing links in backend from frontend

Tags: theming, panels

So im new to drupal and i'm learning on how to use custom theme's by reading [theming drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/). There is a topic about [sub theming](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/creating-sub-themes) and I thought it was interesting to make a sub theme from the default admin theme seven. So I just follow the steps adding all the regions also.

So my frontend is having this as content (default stuff);
[image: frontend content]

### **But the problem is, it is also showing it in the backend;**

[image: backend content]

While i didnt change anything special, i just added a

- myfirstsubtheme.info.yml
- myfirstsubtheme.libraries.yml

With the info provided at the [sub theming](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/creating-sub-themes).

So what am i missing, to make it look like this (when seven is selected as admin theme);
[image]

Also an important note: When I changed my theme to any other theme, it also showed the frontend stuff (so exact the same problem)...